# Exporting Panther functional classification of gene list

Tags: public-databases, data-download, functional-annotation

After inputting a list of gene and running an analysis in https://www.pantherdb.org/ (such as "functional classification"), I get a result table that is limited  by an X number of entries per page. I can select some entries from the table and export that subset as a text. But, Is there a simple way of exporting/downloading the whole functional classification for my gene list as a txt?

Comment: Do you mean this? https://i.imgur.com/ZF7C06f.png Or is that what you tried and it doesn't work for you?

Comment: I tried that but only exports whatever is paginated on the html OR whatever I can select on the page. I want to get the table for all the thousands of IDs I uploaded.